# Jquery closest method for class outside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to call a class outside the parent div

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_photo', function(event){
  var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    cache: false,
    url:'delete-photo.php',
    data:'delete_id='+del_id,
    beforeSend:function(){
       $(event.target).closest('.photo-over').show();
    },
    success:function(data) {
      $('.editor-photo').load(document.URL + ' .editor-photo-list');
    }
 });

});
```

and here is my html

```
<div class="row editor-photo-list">
   {foreach from=$row item=$image_file}
      <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

         <div class="photo-list">
               <input id="{$image_file.id}" type='image' src='http://demo1.demaxglobal.com/content/uploads/editor-images/{$image_file.path}' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('{$image_file.id}', 'http://demo1.demaxglobal.com/content/uploads/editor-images/{$image_file.path}');">

               <div class="photo-over">
                   <div class="line"></div>    
                   <div class="line"></div>    
                   <div class="line"></div>    
                   <div class="line"></div>    
              </div> 
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-12 photo-edit-option">                                                  
               <div class="col-md-4 photo-btn">
                   <div id="{$image_file.path}" class="delete_photo"><img src="../content/themes/default/images/close-button.png">
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 photo-btn">
                  <input id="{$image_file.id}" type='image' src='../content/themes/default/images/photo-edit.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('{$image_file.id}', 'http://demo1.demaxglobal.com/conten/uploads/editor-images/{$image_file.path}');">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 photo-btn">
                    <div class="post_photo-submit" id="{$image_file.path}">
                        <img src="../content/themes/default/images/the-flash.png">
                    </div>
               </div>


    </div>
</div>
{/foreach}

 </div>
```

**Code Updated. Hope this may give you guys some more idea.**

I want to show div photo-over upon clicking the div delete-photo. I tried jquery parent() and find() methods as well but no help.

There are multiple divs with same class name. If I remove the closest method, the photo-over div is showing on all the DIVs.

Thanks

Comment: You can try it: beforeSend:function(){
       $(this).parent().prev().find('.photo-over').show();
    } Also finding this long chain way is not a good practice try to set reference each element.

Comment: Can you move your delete-button? You could place it within the `.photo-list` container as the last child, and then access your `.photo-over` via `$(event.target).prev('.photo-over').show()`

Comment: Regardless of my previous comment, if you were to provide a little more markup for your list, that could clarify things.

Comment: @OliverBaumann Code updated. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a functional class to this line of markup, it is the wrapper for each item; corresponds to line 3 of your example:

`<div class="col-md-4 item-wrapper" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">`

Then you should be able to access it in your callbacks via:

`$(event.target).parents('.item-wrapper').find('.photo-list).find('.photo-over').show()`

Also, next time please spend some effort in [providing code that we can actually run](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by pasting into places like JSFiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the location, you could do this with vanilla js, with the appropriate pathing:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".delete_photo")).map(el => {
  el.onclick = e => {
    const phOver = el.parentElement.previousSibling.querySelector('.photo-over')
    // make your Ajax request, then do `$(phOver).show()`
  }
})
```

With jQuery it should simply be:

```
$(".delete_photo").click(function(e) {
  const sec = $(this).parent().prev()
  // make your Ajax request, then do `$(".photo-over", sec).show()`
})
```

Comment: i did not try the vanilla js method but the jQuery method didn't work for me. I believe you have noticed that delete_photos and photo-over have different parents.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a combination of `parent()`, `prev()` and `find()` methods to navigate to the required `.photo-over` element.

`$(event.target).parent().parent().prev().find('.photo-over')` navigates to the immediately previous `.photo-over` element.

This should work for you:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_photo', function(event) {
  var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: 'delete-photo.php',
    data: 'delete_id=' + del_id,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $(event.target).parent().parent().prev().find('.photo-over').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.editor-photo').load(document.URL + ' .editor-photo-list');
    }
  });
});
```